# Managing the neo4j index's life cycle (CRUD)

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I have limited (and disjointed) experience with databases, and nearly none with indexes. Based on web search, reading books, and working with ORMs my understanding can be summed up as follows:

- An index  in  databases is similar to a book  index in that it  lists "stuff" that's in the book and tells you where  to find it. This helps with lookup efficiency (this is most probably not the only benefit)
- In (at least some) RDBMS's, primary key fields get  automatically indexed so u never have to directly manipulate them.

I'm tinkering with neo4j and it seems you have to be deliberate about indexes so now I need to understand them but I cannot find clear answers to:

- How are indexes managed in neo4j?
- I know there's automatic indexing, how does it work?
- If you choose to manually manage your own indexes, what can you control about them? Perhaps,index name, etc?

Would appreciate answers or pointers to answers, thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j uses Apache Lucene under the covers if you want index engine like capabilities for your data. You can index nodes and/or relationships- the index helps you look up a particular instance/set of nodes or relationships.

**Manual Indexing:**

You can create as many node/relationship indexes as you want and you can specify a name for each index. The config can also be controlled i.e. whether you want exact matching (the default) or Lucenes full text indexing support. Once you have the index, you simply add nodes/relationships to it and the key/value you want indexed. You do however need to take care of "updating" data in the index yourself if you make changes to the node properties.

**Auto-Indexing:**

Here you get one index for nodes and one index for relations if you turn them on in the neo4j.properties file. You may specify what properties are to be indexed and from the point of turning them on, the index is automatically managed for you i.e. any nodes created after this point are added to the index and updated/removed automatically.

**More reading:**
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html

The above applies to versions < 2.0

2.0 adds more around the concept of indexing itself, you might want to go through

http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels

http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/04/nodes-are-people-too.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. I think I'm going to use auto indexing because apparently, it's the only way to ensure that new nodes and relationships get indexed (in the current stable release). Will check out labels as well, thanx